# How to change the input text color to white from black in flutter textformfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

My app background color is black. So the input text color is not visible. So that I need to change the input text color from black to white.

```
Widget showPasswordInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        cursorColor: Colors.white,
        obscureText: true,
        autofocus: false,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            hintText: 'Password',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.lock,
              color: Colors.white,
            )),
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Password can\'t be empty' : null,
        onSaved: (value) => _password = value.trim(),
      ),
    );   
}
```

Comment: `TextFormField` constructor has `TextStyle style` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TextStyle property of TextFormField

```
  Widget showPasswordInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        maxLines: 1,
        cursorColor: Colors.white,
        obscureText: true,
        autofocus: false,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            hintText: 'Password',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.lock,
              color: Colors.white,
            )),
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Password can\'t be empty' : null,
        onSaved: (value) => _password = value.trim(),
      ),
    );

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

TextFormField has a `style` property which you can use.

```dart
TextFormField(
   ...
   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
)
```

To convert the TextField's color, you can surround it with a Theme or modify the MaterialApp theme as well.